# Why is stdbool.h deprecated?

Tags: c, c11, stdbool

The [C standard now says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/stdbool.h.html):

> The ability to undefine and redefine the macros bool, true, and false is an obsolescent feature and may be removed in a future version.

That is, `stdbool.h` is deprecated.  But no rationale is given and I couldn't find one.  Do they intend on adding bool as a basic type for good or is there something else ?

If you happen to know why this is deprecated, thank you for telling me !

Comment: Why do you think `stdbool.h` is deprecated?

Comment: `"ability to undefine and redefine the macros"` != `stdbool.h`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why is stdbool.h deprecated?

It's not.

You quoted the following note:

> The ability to undefine and redefine the macros bool, true, and false is an obsolescent feature and may be removed in a future version.

What this means is that the following paragraph may be removed in the future:

> An application may undefine and then possibly redefine the macros bool, true, and false.

That does not mean that the header or its contents will be removed.

Comment: I think the intention of that text is to allow `<stdbool.h>` to do something other than defining `true` and `false` as macros equivalent to `0` and `1` (e.g. define them as macros which expand to compiler intrinsics `__true` and `__false`--perhaps to help a compiler generate more useful diagnostics).  Such handling would be undermined by an application that undefined those macros and redefined them as 0 and 1.

Comment: but that doesn't mean that `<stdbool.h>` is deprecated.... I'm afraid.  What it probably means is that because the existence of `<stdbool.h>` header, ***the task of defining macros for `true` or `false` and `bool` is what is deprecated.***

Answer (score 6):

There are a few misunderstandings in your question:

- The first is that you link to a POSIX reference, which often follow the C Standard, but it doesn't have to.
- The section you quote from is *informative* and not factual, and as such may not reflect the C standard at all. And as such it isn't authoritative either.
- The quote also says it's the ability for *users* to undefine or redefine the macros is what could be taken away. The macros in the [`<stdbool.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/boolean) header file would not be affected by this.
- Lastly, it also says the possibility ***might*** be taken away, not that it will or have been.